# Jenkins pipeline stuck on build job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I recently create a new jenkins pipeline that mainly relies on other build jobs. Strange thing is, the 1st stage job gets triggered, ran successfully + Finished with "SUCCESS" state. But the pipeline keeps on loading forever after Scheduling project: "run-operation".

Any idea what mistake i made below? 
UPDATE 1: remove param with hard coded advertiser & query

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'slave'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                script{
                    def buildResult = build job: 'run-operation', parameters: [
                        string(name: 'ADVERTISER', value: 'car'), 
                        string(name: 'START_DATE', value: '2019-12-29'), 
                        string(name: 'END_DATE', value: '2020-01-11'), 
                        string(name: 'QUERY', value: 'weekly')
                    ]
                    def envVar = buildResult.getBuildVariables();
                }
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo 'track the query operations from above job'
                    def trackResult = build job: 'track-operation', parameters: [
                        string(name: 'OPERATION_NAMES', value: envVar.operationList), 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                echo 'move flag'
                }

        }
        stage('callback') {
            steps {
                echo 'for each operation call back url'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console log (despite the job was running, the pipeline doesnt seems to know, see log):

```
Started by user reusable
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/etl-pipeline/workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (1)
[Pipeline] build (Building run-operation)
Scheduling project: run-operation)
...
```

Comment: Can you share console output/logs of the execution? And is there any other configuration  in Jenkins job/pipeline from UI ? Params, SCM, Polling etc?

Comment: hi @saurabh14292, i attached the console log. Also replaced the param with hard coded value to make it simpler, and i didnt change other configuration in UI, no SCM, no polling.

Comment: Your step 2 has an invocation to  another job. Maybe this job never ends.

Comment: You are triggering Jenkins job from stage 1 and 2 of your pipeline. Are you sure they are returning success/exit code? IMO, you should not trigger jobs from pipeline, but have the actual working of job within pipeline itself as a code.